# Pass value of textarea when submit button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html

```
<textarea id="Comment" type="text" runat="server" rows="7" 
maxlength="2000" />

<input id="SubmitComment" type="button" value="Submit"
onclick="SubmitButton()" />
```

When the user enters data into the textarea and clicks the 'Submit' button I want the data to be passed to the submitButton() where I can then send it on to Functions.CommentBoxForInvoiceUpdates

```
function SubmitButton() {
var commentBoxData = $('#Comment').val();
Functions.CommentBoxForInvoiceUpdates(id, Labour, commentBoxData);
        }
```

Id and Labour are defined earlier so they work fine, 'CommentBoxData' however is showing up as undefined when I run it through a break point.
Any why the data in the comment box is being sent through when submit is clicked?

Thanks for any ideas

Comment: Can you create a fiddle

Answer (score 1):

You tagged with asp.net. Sure you are using the rendered IDs?

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
var commentBoxData = $('#<%=Comment.ClientID%>').val();
```